# python beautiful soup crawling with json

Tags: python, html, json, request, beautifulsoup

I'm new to beautifulsoup in python and I"m trying to extract certain information from a website. The deeplink and the title

I use beautifulsoup to extract json and got my beautifulsoup.beautifulsoup variable soup.

But I did not manage to extract the desired information yet.

HTML block being harvested:

```
<div class="activities-list horizontal">
<article data-href="http://www.getyourguide.de/london-l57/windsor-bath-und- stonehenge-tagesausflug-ab-london-t977/" id="t977" class="activity-card activity-card-horizontal
">
<div class="activity-card-content">
<a class="activity-card-link" href="http://www.getyourguide.de/london-l57/windsor-bath-und-stonehenge-tagesausflug-ab-london-t977/">
<div class="activity-card-image-container">
<img src="http://img.getyourguide.com/img/tour_img-206771-70.jpg" data- role="cover" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="activity-card-details">
<header class="activity-card-header">
<h3 class="activity-card-title">
Stonehenge, Windsor und Bath - Tagesausflug ab London
</h3>
<div class="activity-rating">
<span class="rating" title="Bewertung: 3,9 von 5">
<span class="rating-stars s30"></span>
<span class="rating-total">13 Bewertungen</span>
</span>                     </div>
</header>
<p class="activity-small-description">Verlassen Sie London und entdecken Sie    Reize der englischen Landschaft auf einer Ganztagestour, die Sie zu berühmten,   historischen Orten führt.…</p>
<div class="activity-info activity-duration">
<span class="activity-info-label activity-duration-label">
```

Dauer:
    
    
     10 Stunden
    
    
    
    
    
    Ab
    
     € 75
    
    
    
    Jetzt buchen

I would like to parse out the deeplinks (href) and title (activity-card-title). Here is my logic so far:

```
 response = urlopen("http://www.getyourguide.de/s/search.json?    q=London&page=8")
 content = response.read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
 newDictionary = json.loads(str(soup))['activities'].get("href")
 print(newDictionary)
```

Result:

```
  newDictionary = json.loads(str(soup))['activities'].get("href")
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Any feedback is appreciated:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser',from_encoding='utf-8')
```

for deeplinks:

```
links = soup.find_all('a',href=True)
```

for titles:

```
titles = soup.find_all('div',{'class':'activity-card-title'})
```

if there is only 1 title in block use only find

```
title  = soup.find('div',{'class':'activity-card-title'})
```

Comment: It still does not work. Getting an empty result []. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The AttributeError you're getting is because you're trying to load the whole soup with json, which can't be done. It looks like you want the content of the `<p>` tag, and then you can load that into json. You can get that like this, and get the activities value like a normal dictionary.

```
activities = json.loads(soup.find('p').text)['activities']
```

But then it gets a little weird because we're not dealing with the soup anymore, we just have a big string that looks like some html. So we can make a new soup with that, and get the deeplinks and title from the resulting soup.

```
newsoup = BeautifulSoup(activities)

links = newsoup.find_all('a', href=True)
deeplinks = [ a['href'] for a in links ]

titles = newsoup.find_all('h3', 'activity-card-title')
```